# How can I multiply an HTML character entity reference or &nbsp;?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to draw a rectangle with a function in JavaScript, and I need to multiply the HTML character entity reference `&nbsp;` to draw the spaces between the sides.

Can I save the *character entity reference* on a variable and then multiply it like in Python?

```
function drawRectangle(side, figure) {
    var spaces = "&nbsp;";
    for (var i=0; i < side; i++) {
        document.write(figure);
    }
    for (var i=0; i< side-2; i++) {
        document.write(figure + spaces*side + figure);
    }
    document.write("<br>");
    for (var i=0; i < side; i++) {
        document.write(figure);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use CSS positioning.

Comment: I need to do it with javascript

Comment: `spaces.repeat(side)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&nbsp;` isn't a tag. It's a [character entity reference.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

To do *exactly* what you're asking, you're going to want to "repeat" the string, not multiply it. If you're in an environment which supports it, you can use the [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) function.

```js
var input = '&nbsp;';
var output = input.repeat(3);
console.log(output);
```

If your environment does *not* support it, you can write one of your own.

```js
function repeatStr(str, count) {
  return new Array(count + 1).join(str);
}

var input = '&nbsp;';
var output = repeatStr(input, 3);
console.log(output);
```

Note that you [should really avoid using `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) and what you're trying to do is likely easier to do with CSS.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0F0;
  /* This will move it to the right */
  margin-left: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```
function drawRectangle(side, figure){
  var spaces = "&nbsp;";
  for (var i=0; i < side; i++) {         
    document.write(figure);
  }
  for (var i=0; i< side-2; i++){
    document.write(figure + spaces.repeat(side) + figure);
  }
  document.write("<br>");
  for (var i=0; i < side; i++) {
    document.write(figure);
  }
}
```

Note: this may not be supported in all browsers, so you can use the polyfill provided by MDN, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).